# Create filtered list view in Calendar using JavaScript/JSOM

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

I am attempting to create a filtered list view in a Calendar. It is creating everything as appropriate, but not creating the filters. It believe it's my CAML. My goal is to filter by a choice column named "Approval Status" with a value of "Approved":

```
    function createCalendarView() {

        var currentcontext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var hostcontext = new SP.AppContextSite(currentcontext, hostweburl);
        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();           
        var hostweb = hostcontext.get_web();
        var listCollection = hostweb.get_lists();
        var list = listCollection.getByTitle('Calendar');

        // Create Approved PTO View
        //get the view collection to add the view
        var viewcollection = list.get_views();
        //create a viewinfo with the view properties
        var viewInfo = new SP.ViewCreationInformation(); //create multiple views
        viewInfo.set_title("MYVIEW"); //set the title
        viewInfo.set_viewTypeKind(524288);
        viewInfo.set_setAsDefaultView(true); //set the view to default
        var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Approval Status"/><Value Type="Text">Approved</Value></Eq></Where></View>');
        viewInfo.set_query(camlQuery);
        //add the view to the view collection
        viewcollection.add(viewInfo);


        //load the view collection
        context.load(viewcollection);
        context.executeQueryAsync(onCalendarViewCreationSuccess, onCalendarViewCreationFail);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This was answered at [JSOM: Create Filtered Calendar View](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/42db8c9b-d402-417f-aafb-59d09360892d/jsom-create-filtered-calendar-view?forum=appsforsharepoint&prof=required)

Using the format of worked. There is no Query in the Caml:

```
camlQuery.set_viewXml("<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Approval_x0020_Status' /><Value Type='Choice'>Approved</Value></Eq></Where>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Approval Status\'/><Value Type=\'Text\'>Approved</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');
```

Comment: No such luck. It is still creating the view without the filter applied. Does it matter that its a Calendar?

Comment: test the query using CAML query builder and check it returns proper data. Also try to create a view using SharePoint UI and see if filter is working.

Comment: It appears to be tied to the Calendar, as it asks for the "Calendar Columns" to be filled in before applying the filter

Comment: Any suggestions on how to create a filtered calendar view with JSOM? I believe we need to set the calendar columns first